# How to place progressbar on a layout element like a textview or an imageview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, android-cardview

I am loading a list from server using Retrofit. 
Can anyone help me how to load ProgressBar at each element of the CardViewin the RecyclerView?
 Below I am posting an image of what I want to do.
[image: Example]

Edit:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewMargin"
            android:id="@+id/rvRecyclerViewCustom"
            >
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Post the layout XML of your `RecyclerView` item.

Comment: There is no easy way. Wrap your `ImageView` and `ProgressBar` in a `FrameLayout`. Then, when your image is loaded, hide the `ProgressBar`. Most image loading libraries provide a way of doing this.

Comment: @Ali and what about the TextView ?

Comment: Same thing... you can also set a compound drawable that is animated for textviews (drawableStart, drawableEnd, drawableTop, drawableBottom). That being said, I think one indicator is enough why do you need one on each element?

Comment: @Ali actully it's a TabLayout as you  can see so if I am using a single progressbar then it is not a good experience for user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How to set it on TextView?

Comment: @Sushrita change the ImageView into TextView